# zabbix - install multiple ezbbix agent version

Tags: zabbix

i want to install multiple agent zabbix version, but when i i want install an agent zabbix i have this message :

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> PS C:\Windows\system32>
 C:\zabbix\bin\zabbix_agentd.exe --config
 C:\zabbix\conf\zabbix_agentd.win.conf --install zabbix_agentd.exe
 [9624]: ERROR: service [Zabbix Agent] already exists
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrYDw.png)

i want to know multiple zabbix agent version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use --multiple-agents option

```
zabbix_agentd.exe --config <configuration_file_for_instance_1> --install --multiple-agents
```

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/install/windows_agent